# SQL Intersection of 2 queries based on common column in the same table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the result of 2 queries and would like to intersect these results based on a common column in both. Here  time is a common column

How to achieve this? I'm using a SQLite database

Query #1:

```
select ltp as ltp_17sep, time 
from table 
where symbol = "AAPL" and expiry = "17SEP2020"

 +--------------------+---------------------+
 |         ltp_17sep  |        time         |
 +--------------------+---------------------+
 |              19.63 | 2020-09-11T04:25:00 |
 | 19.470000000000002 | 2020-09-11T04:30:00 |
 |              19.79 | 2020-09-11T04:35:00 |
 |              19.52 | 2020-09-11T04:40:00 |
```

Query# 2:

```
select ltp as ltp_24sep, time 
from table 
where symbol = "AAPL" and expiry = "24SEP2020"

 +--------------------+---------------------+
 |         ltp_24sep  |        time         |
 +--------------------+---------------------+
 |              17.63 | 2020-09-11T04:25:00 |
 | 18.470000000000002 | 2020-09-11T04:30:00 |
 |              16.79 | 2020-09-11T04:55:00 |
 |              17.52 | 2020-09-11T05:40:00 |
```

Expected result: intersection result should be based on common time column:

```
 +--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
 |     ltp_17sep      |     ltp_24sep      |        time         |
 +--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
 |              19.63 |              17.63 | 2020-09-11T04:25:00 |
 |              19.47 |              18.47 | 2020-09-11T04:30:00 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a simple self join:

```
select t1.ltp ltp_17sep, t2.ltp ltp_24sep, t1.time
from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2
on t2.time = t1.time
where t1.symbol = 'AAPL' and t2.symbol = 'AAPL'
  and t1.expiry = '17SEP2020' and t2.expiry = '24SEP2020'
```

Or cteate a CTE for each of your queries and join them:

```
with
  cte1 as (select ltp,time from tablename where symbol='AAPL' and expiry='17SEP2020'),
  cte2 as (select ltp,time from tablename where symbol='AAPL' and expiry='24SEP2020')
select c1.ltp ltp_17sep, c2.ltp ltp_24sep, c1.time
from cte1 c1 inner join cte2 c2
on c2.time = c1.time
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=361239f3302d3aa598d4e73ff2070b7d).
Results:

```
> ltp_17sep | ltp_24sep | time               
> --------: | --------: | :------------------
>     19.63 |     17.63 | 2020-09-11T04:25:00
>     19.47 |     18.47 | 2020-09-11T04:30:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do an inner join on the time column.

```
SELECT a1, a2, b1, b2
FROM A
INNER JOIN B on B.f = A.f
WHERE <conditions>
```

This takes rows where the `f` column are the same, `time` in your case and joins the columns and discards any rows where `f` doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select symbol, time
       max(case when expiry= '17SEP2020' then ltp end) as ltp_17sep
       max(case when expiry= '24SEP2020' then ltp end) as ltp_24sep
from table
where symbol = 'AAPL' and
      expiry ( '17SEP2020', '24SEP2020' )
group by symbol, time
having count(*) = 2;
```